# Where to find documentations for the events in event logs?

Tags: apache-superset

In the documentation it is said, that Superset by default logs special action events in its internal database. These logs can be accessed on the UI by navigating to Security > Action Log. But what do the various actions refer to? where can I find documentation for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe there is any documentation for this. But there is a significant effort underway to improve documentation. What are you looking for, specifically?

Comment: I'm trying out Superset and I have some dataset, charts, dashboard and I want to see how my use (activity) on the dashboard, e.g accessing a dataset and e.g. download the data is reflected in the event log. When I browse around in my dashboard and charts I see a lots of events in the activity log but I can not relate them to my activity.